# Copy from PhpStorm, paste elsewhere with spaces (NOT TABS)

Tags: copy, phpstorm, indentation, copy-paste, spacing

Whenever I copy over a snippet of code from PhpStorm and paste into another application, it copies over its "tab-spacing" *(where 4 spaces is one tab)* . This causes problems with my other app.

Can I have PhpStorm copy using "space spacing" instead?

Comment: So .. you want that make PhpStorm to **modify** the copied text (which has tabs) to convert tabs into spaces automatically?

Comment: I guess, or have it automatically set with spaces only (when I press tab it adds 4 spaces)

Comment: As I understand: you have some code/text that is formatted using tabs for indents. Now you want to copy the selected text elsewhere and replace those tabs by spaces. *I initially assumed* that you wish to have such conversion automatic (on normal Copy) ... which is simply bad idea/unexpected behaviour in my opinion. But as a separate action -- why not (e.g. similar to "Export as CSV" for table data). Unfortunately PhpStorm does not have such functionality built-in. I may only suggest checking available plugins -- there are few that work with text and maybe one of them can do that.

Comment: "Now you want to copy the selected text elsewhere and replace those tabs by spaces." yes thats what I wanted. I'll just have to use autohotkey to do this probably, I have this problem with every IDE I use. My notetaking app/code snippet manager cannot handle [tab] spacing. Normaly I run it through an online "HTML / CSS" clean up tool to format it the way I want too. But that takes too long.

Comment: OK. What about using spaces as indents in actual source files (Code Style)? Or that is something that you cannot do ... or it may still somehow get into the code elsewhere? What you may do here (using IDE only): copy your fragment in a separate/special file .. and then use `Edit | Convert Indents | To Spaces` on it (it works on selected text fragment); after that -- copy & paste into your snippet app. Yeah -- still 2 steps. See if you can partially automate it via Macro functionality or something else.

Comment: Okay I used your "Convert Indents" suggestion, I posted what it looks like as an answer here. Also, I posted another autohotkey question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165942/autohotkey-clipboard-convert-tabs-to-spaces , which is related to this one (Same problem, different approach)

Answer (score 0):

The good enough lazy answer for the time being

1. Highlight code
2. edit → Convert Indents (to Spaces)
3. Hold ALT + Select code
4. CTRL+C copy
5. Ctrl+Z (to undo the changes from converting tabs to spaces)
6. CTRL+V Paste into my code snippet app

[image]

End result looks good. App I'm using is https://dynalist.io for code snippet management

[image]