# Autohotkey : Clipboard Convert Tabs to Spaces

Tags: text, format, clipboard, autohotkey, copy-paste

I have a snippet of code I copied into my clipboard. Pasting it out looks like this. Where[tab] is an actual tab indent

```
[tab]<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
[tab][tab]<h1>
[tab][tab][tab]<h2>
[tab][tab][tab][tab]<h3>
[tab][tab][tab][tab][tab]<h4>;
```

I want to press an autohotkey to automatically normalize the code snippet. So if there's a [tab] on every line, remove it.
Then convert each [tab] into 2 spaces [**]

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
**<h1>
****<h2>
******<h3>
********<h4>;
```

So the general workflow is:

1. Copy code to clipboard
2. Press an autohotkey
3. Paste the newly formatted contents

Pseudocode for autohotkey would look like this

- Dig through every clipboard content line by line
- If every item shares an equal number of [tab] spaces, remove them entirely
- Line by line, convert [tab] to [**] 2 spaces

Answer (score 2):

```
; convert each tab into 2 spaces:

clipboard =
(
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <h1>
            <h2>
                <h3>
                    <h4>;
)
clipboard := StrReplace(clipboard, A_Tab, A_Space A_Space)
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm

Comment: this works really good. Also, is there a way to remove the first [tab] of every line, if all other lines have a first line [tab]?

Comment: Possibly just check if line1 has a [tab] in it, then remove a tab off everyline?

Answer (score 0):

okay problem solved I have everything I want now. I took the other source code snippet [here on autohotkey forum](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/113993-how-to-remove-leading-spaces-from-each-line-in-string/)

```
F9::
clipboard := StrReplace(clipboard, A_Tab, A_Space A_Space)
position := RegExMatch(clipboard, "\S")
test := RegExReplace(clipboard, "m)^[ ]{" . position - 1 . "}")
clipboard := test
```

As a reference, need to highlight the full line on code snippet like so

[image]

So all I have to do now is:

1. Copy the full code
2. Press F9
3. Paste into my notetaking app (dynalist.io with codesnippet support)